# Issues Using JSON.Net to serialize from JSON to XML - C#

Tags: c#, json, ajax, xml, json.net

I am attempting to use AJAX to send a JSON object from the client side to the server. I would like to take the JSON and serialize it as xml and store it in a SQL Server.

I am performing a POST and sending the JSON as a string using :

```
    var Full_JSON = products_json[product_id];
    var Message = "";

    if (FULL_JSON == null) {
        Message = "No Products_JSON!";
    }

    if (Message.length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            url: "/Query.asmx/InsertXMLJSON",  
            data: "{'JSON':'" + JSON.stringify(Full_JSON) + "'}",
            success: function (Record) {
                if (Record.d == true) {
                    console.log("AJAX Success: " + JSON.stringify(Record));
                }
                else {
                    console.log("AJAX Fail: " + JSON.stringify(Record));
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        })
    }
```

I then take the "JSON" string that is passed and call:

```
public static bool InsertXMLJSON(string UserEmail, string Time, string Product, string JSON)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JSON, "root");
}
```

When this is called I get the exception shown below:

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: Q. Path
>   'Calculations.1.Calculation_Logic', line 1, position 4167.

Here is a snippet of the JSON string where the character is encountered:

```
\"Calculation_Logic\":\"Math.round((products_json[product_id][\"Questions\"][1][\"Answer\"])/(products_json[product_id][\"Questions\"][3][\"Answer\"]))\"
```

I have noticed that the escaping of the quotations within the square bracket seems to be part of the issue. If I remove the quotations it parses it just fine.

Any idea why this would be causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you stringifying simple string variable called Full_JSON. You tried to send it instead of JSON.stringify(Full_JSON)? Without full code sample it is hard to understand what exactly you are stringifying, but it probably the cause. For example:

```
var str = '{"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}}';
var obj = {"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}};

//this one looks very similar to your problem
console.log( JSON.stringify(str) );  // {\"2003\":{\"1\":{\"2\":[\"test\"],\"3\":[\"test2\"]}}} 

//and this one is correct use of this component
console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) );  // {"2003":{"1":{"2":["test"],"3":["test2"]}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have uploaded a code snippet for the AJAX. I am calling JSON.stringify directly on the JSON object.